# Raising a negative real base to an irrational number

Tags: complex-analysis

When we raise a negative real base to an irrational number we get an infinite number of complex roots. 
Can we calculate some of these roots?

Example:

$y=(-2)^{π} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition used in complex analysis is $a^b = \exp(b \log(a))$ where $\log (a)$ is any branch of the complex logarithm of $a$.  Thus this is a multivalued function.

Thus in your example, $\log(-2) = \ln(2) + i (2n +1) \pi$ where $n$ is an arbitrary integer, and so
$$ (-2)^\pi = \exp(\pi (\ln(2) + i (2n+1)\pi)) = 2^\pi \left(\cos((2n+1)\pi^2) + i \sin((2n+1)\pi^2)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming principle branch, $$(-2)^\pi=(2e^{i\pi})^\pi=2^\pi e^{i\pi^2}=2^\pi\left(\cos \pi^2+i\sin \pi^2\right)$$